# The convolution identity of the bell polynomials $x_n^{k\diamond}$

Tags: notation, definition, convolution

On Wikipedia's [Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) Convolution identity.
The convolution identity for the sequence
\begin{equation}
x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)
\end{equation}
defined the operation
$(x\diamond y)_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i} x_{i} y_{n-i}$

This then defined an operation
\begin{equation}
x_n^{k\diamond}
\end{equation}
the $n$th term of the k convolution of
\begin{equation}
x\diamond...\diamond x 
\end{equation}
where an example was given by
\begin{equation}
x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,....)
\end{equation}

However, this confused me of how to obtain
\begin{equation}
x\diamond x 
=(0, 2x_1^2,6x_1x_2, 8x_1x_3+ 6x_2^2,...)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x\diamond x\diamond x
=(0,0,6x_1^3, 36 x_1^2 x_2,...)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
B_{4,3}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{(x\diamond x\diamond x)_4}{3!} =6x_1^2x_2
\end{equation}
because
\begin{equation}
(x_1,x_2)\diamond (x_1,x_2) =\binom{2}{1} x_1x_1 =2x_1^2
\end{equation}
I don't see where did the $0$ in $x\diamond x$ or $6x_1x_2$ come from.

What's the correct definition for this expression?

Comment: I think you mean $n\choose{i}$ instead of $n\choose{j}$ in your definition of $(x\diamond y)_n$.

Comment: @Scene Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
(x\diamond y)_n&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}x_jy_{n-j}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\\
(x\diamond y)&=\left((x\diamond y)_1,(x\diamond y)_2,(x\diamond y)_3,\ldots\right)\\
&=\left((x\diamond y)_n\right)_{n\geq 1}
\end{align*}
We obtain according to this definition
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x\diamond x)_1}&=\sum_{j=1}^{0}\binom{1}{j}x_jx_{1-j}\color{blue}{=0}\tag{$\to$ empty sum}\\
\color{blue}{(x\diamond x)_2}&=\sum_{j=1}^1\binom{2}{j}x_jx_{2-j}=\binom{2}{1}x_1x_1\color{blue}{=2x_1^2}\\
\color{blue}{(x\diamond x)_3}&=\sum_{j=1}^2\binom{3}{j}x_jx_{3-j}\\
&=\binom{3}{1}x_1x_2+\binom{3}{2}x_2x_1\color{blue}{=6x_1x_2}\\
\color{blue}{(x\diamond x)_4}&=\sum_{j=1}^3\binom{4}{j}x_jx_{4-j}\\
&=\binom{4}{1}x_1x_3+\binom{4}{2}x_2x_2+\binom{4}{3}x_3x_1\\
&\color{blue}{=8x_1x_3+6x_2^2}
\end{align*}
It follows
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x\diamond x)=(0,2x_1^2,6x_1x_2,8x_1x_3+6x_2^2,\ldots)}
\end{align*}
The expression
\begin{align*}
(x\diamond x\diamond x)=((x\diamond x)\diamond x)=(x\diamond (x\diamond x))
\end{align*}
can be calculated analogously.